# How to transform/modify a js file during a release in Azure DevOps

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-devops, angular5, azure-pipelines

**Scenario/Current state:** I have an Angular 5 project which is on Azure DevOps. I push to Dev/Test and Prod from same branch (master). I have environment.ts file set up for my build so when I build my project from master it picks up the BaseAPIURL's depending on which environment I am building in. My master branch always using the command using `run-script build --env=dev`.

**What I am trying to achieve:** I want to have one Build and multiple "Release" plans for different environment. By default upon build all the angular code is converted to .js files in my "dist" folder. The environment variable is present in `main.bundle.js`. How can I transform/modify that file during a release ?

Comment: I think that it's a bad idea to modify any JS code after it was built. There is an option to use an `APP_INITIALIZER` factory which can get some config from wherever (I get it via `http.get` from json file in `assets` folder) where you can set all your environments and their corresponding settings. Then you just need to pick the one you need.

Comment: Can APP_INITIALIZER grab variables defined on DevOps Azure for the individual releases ?

Comment: Not sure about that. Try to check it out.

Comment: @HereToLearn_ Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with **Sergey**, is not recommended to do it, but I did it in the past in an angular project.

It's simple, install [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension, in your `environment.ts` file put a placeholders for the values, for example:

```
baseUrl = __baseUrl__
```

In the release pipeline add a variable `baseUrl` for each environment with different value.

[image]

Now in each release environment (stage) add the replace tokens task and configure it to search the pattern `__{variable}__`:

[image]

So do it for all the variables (just add them in the variables tab and put the placeholders in the file).

If you want to use `APP_INITIALIZER` you can read [this](https://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2017/07/27/managing-settings-for-an-angular-app-with-vsts) post that explain hot to do it with Azure DevOps.